# how to compare a string in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array and I use ng-repeat to display the items in the array. However, I want to compare if the array contains the word "doctor". And if it contains doctor, I need to do some logic.

My array is as follows

fields : ['research','doctor','educator']

How do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to to do in pure Javascript:

```
['research','doctor','educator'].each(function(val){
  if (val == 'doctor') {
    console.log("I'm a doctor");
  }   
});
```

Or with [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
['research','doctor','educator'].filter(function(val){
  if (val == 'doctor') {
    return val;
  }   
});
```

You can use a custom filter, where you can apply the same logic as described in my answer. Here is a very nice article about this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters.

So you pass a parameter as a filter value to your custom filter function, then in your html markup you apply the filter function.

Comment: Simo, thank you but this is not what I wanted. Because, everything is dynamic and I get these from angular service all these arrays. In the HTML we are not supposed to use these javascripts as per our project paradigm. So was wondering if there are ng-repeat filters etc

Answer (score 1):

In html, I used filter, have a good day.

```html
<span ng-if="(fields | filter: 'doctor': true )[0]">
            do something ...
 </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `===` operator, for example:

```
var1 = 'hello';
console.log(var1 === 'hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   <script>
    var _firstArray =  ['research','doctor','educator'];
    var _secondArray=_firstArray;
    _firstArray.forEach(function(item){
        console.log(item); 
        console.log('test'); 
      if (_secondArray.indexOf(item) !==-1){
         console.log(item)  
      }
      else{
      console.log("not matched");
      }
    })

    </script>
```

or

```
 <script>
    var _firstArray =  ['research','doctor','educator'];
    var _secondArray='doctor';
    _firstArray.forEach(function(item){
        console.log(item); 
        console.log('test'); 
      if (_secondArray.indexOf(item) !==-1){
         console.log(item)  
      }
      else{
      console.log("not matched");
      }
    })

    </script>
```

Comment: also you can add second string as per your require